# Async process I/O with netty?

Tags: java, asynchronous, ipc, netty

I want to fork off a subprocess, feed it incoming data from a Channel and stream back the result to the client. So far the best solution I've come with is to put an [OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.1/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/execution/OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor.html%20%22OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor) in front of my upstream handler which forks off another thread to read the output from the process and write it back on the channel. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Check your terminology.  "fork off a subprocess" has clear meaning on Linux that you wish to create a new process with a unique pid.  But I think you mean you wish to create a new worker thread and hand off the workload for a Channel to this thread.  threads != processes

Comment: I do mean creating a new process with a unique pid. As a simple example, I'd like to fork off 'cat', feed channel data into it, get back the output and stream it back to the client. ATM, I'm having to create a new thread that spawns the process and shovels data back and forth. This is because I didn't want to put blocking code in the  netty worker thread and I couldn't figure out how to do truly async subprocess I/O. Hope that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own thread pool to submit new thread in your job handler. OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor is a wrapper of standard excutorservice. The advantage of it is it can calculate the memory cost. You can get better control of your own logic by using your own thread pool. As told in netty tutorial, you need to fork a new thread for job handling. The I/O is bound to a socket, which is hidden inside a netty channel. You need to pass channel or channel context into that new thread. The socket is always there, and the async IO is performed by reading/writing to the socket in the new thread.